# why R shows this matrix is not positive.definite

Tags: r, matrix

R tells me my matrix is not definite positive.
when I return the 2*2 matrix all elements are 3.033e+307.

is nt this a positive definite matrix? why R says it is not?

Comment: First, this likely is better suited for [stats.se] or [math.se]. Second, the theoretical discussion might be helpful, but *your matrix* might have some nuance that you don't know about; unfortunately, neither do we, we don't have it. Please provide sample data using `dput(.)` or build it programmatically, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: If all elements are the same the matrix is not positive definite, only positive semidefinite.